# How to group elements of array

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
var arr = ['User1','123456','User2','456789','User3','546544'];
```

How can I get array of object like this:

```
var arr2 = [{name: 'User1', id: 123456},{name: 'User2', id: 456789}, {name: 'User3', id: 546544}];
```

I tried this:

```
arr.forEach(function (item, i, arr) {
            arr2.push(
                {
                    name: arr[i],
                    id: arr[i + 2]
                }
            );
        });
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Have a look at map and push - even a simple for loop is useful.

Comment: `id: arr[i + 1]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The for loop works on all versions of all computers and has the added advantage of being able to skip the index directly, something forEach can only do with a lot of extra code. Also forEach is slower than the for loop.

```js
var arr1 = ['User1', '123456', 'User2', '456789', 'User3', '546544'], arr2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length - 1; i += 2) { // here is the i+=2
  arr2.push({
    "name": arr1[i],
    "user": arr1[i + 1] // here is the i+1
  });
}
console.log(arr2)
```

Or terser array

```js
var arr1 = ['User1', '123456', 'User2', '456789', 'User3', '546544'], arr2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length - 1; i += 2) {
  arr2.push({
    [arr1[i]]: arr1[i + 1]
  });
}
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Er... Doesn't capture name. Oh, you did it in a totally different way... `:)`

Comment: doesn't include the name and id keys

Comment: Yeah, I just realised

Comment: _But why not_ Maybe the application expects in such a format... `:)`

Comment: @mplungjan second upvote is mine. You do not need to wrap object keys in double quotes tho ... :D

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT That is my style. I love to wrap them to make them similar to a valid JSON. `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman I understand, I was just poking mplungjan :p

Comment: Can the downvoters PLEASE comment their downvote. The script posted WORKS. It is NOT ES6 or 7 - but that only means it runs everywhere without Babel.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, you need to do two things:

1. Check if the length is even.
2. Push it as how you require, by incrementing the loop twice.

```js
var arr = ['User1', '123456', 'User2', '456789', 'User3', '546544'];
var arrObj = [];
if (arr.length % 2 === 0)
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2)
    arrObj.push({
      "name": arr[i],
      "id": parseInt(arr[i + 1], 10),
    });
console.log(arrObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the comments inside the code.

```js
const arr = ['User1', '123456', 'User2', '456789', 'User3', '546544'];

// Ok, so what you to do is to group the infos and create a new object
// There is many function you can use, in the following example, I will use
// Array.reduce

// We gonna call couple, two values that goes together, like :
// User1 and 123456
// User2 and 456789

// ...
const ret = arr.reduce((tmp, x, xi) => {
  // Add nothing for the first value of the couple
  // We gonna ignore, User1, User2 and User3
  if (xi % 2 === 0) return tmp;

  return [
    ...tmp,

    // Add a new value in the array
    {
      // The name is the first value of the couple
      name: arr[xi - 1],

      // The id is the second value of the couple
      id: x,
    },
  ];
}, []);

console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Arrrgh. that is way too complex just to force ES6 on the noob

Comment: Sorry man, an answer, so extensively commented, looks great. At first look, it looks like a low quality answer that just has a code block. So I edited this. Hope that's fine?

Comment: @mplungjan ROFL, true.

Comment: @mplungjan yeah because poorly indented code, whithout any space is way better for 'noobs' to understand. It sure gives them good habits... It's not because the code is compact, that it is better

Comment: So `arr1 = [` declaration deserve a space and `arr2=` doesn't. No space at all in here `var i=0;i<arr1.length-1;i+=2` or even here `arr2.push({[arr1[i]]:arr1[i+1]});`; idk which style guide you use, but I ain't know about it

Comment: @mplungjan Greg is telling that your one-liner will be hard on newbies... Which is true to an extent... `:)`

Comment: No issue about indentation though. I did not click TIDY before I exited. But have now

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman I agree - but he was referring to my poor spacing but called it indentation

Comment: And yes, your extensively commented answer looks nice, but is really hard to read and understand - especially this `return [
    ...tmp,


    {
          name: arr[xi - 1],

          id: x,
    },
  ];` because one needs to know how the parameters work here

Comment: @mplungjan It's not about nice or not, I think it's good for people to find both ways in here. just I get triggered on your first comment

Comment: I agree, but this is really hard on the eyes (and brain), even more with comments `return [ ...tmp, { name: arr[xi - 1], id: x, }, ];`

Answer (score -1):

A solution to your problem would be as follow :

```
var arr2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) {
   arr2.push({name : arr[i], id: arr[i + 1]})
}
```

Next time time try to show your trial code, you'll progress much more this way.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot

Comment: No problem, don't know why people downvote, it's simple efficient solution to your issue, no need for 200 lines.